# How to specify an instance type creating an AWS EC2 instance with the RunInstancesRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to specify an instance type, i.e. “c4.large”, creating an AWS EC2 instance.  The information about new instance is in RunInstanceRequest. How to specify an instance type creating an instance?

Comment: public void setInstanceType(String instanceType), see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.html#setInstanceType-java.lang.String-

Comment: Please show the code you are using to launch the instance.

Comment: @jarmod what is the difference between RunInstanceRequest  methods setInstanceType and withInstaqnceType

Comment: The 'with' variant allows you to chain methods, for example new RunInstanceRequest().withInstanceType('t1.micro').withMinCount(xyz).withMonitoring(xyz). Standard Java pattern.

Comment: @jarmod you can write your note as the answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the instance type in a [RunInstancesRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.html), you can use either:

- [setInstanceType(String instanceType)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.html#setInstanceType-java.lang.String-), or
- [setInstanceType(InstanceType instanceType)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.html#setInstanceType-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceType-)

For example:

```
r = new RunInstancesRequest();
r.setInstanceType('t1.micro');
r.setMinCount(1);
r.setMonitoring(true);
```

Note that there are also `withInstanceType` variants of these methods which allow you to [chain initializer methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), for example:

```
r = new RunInstancesRequest()
    .withInstanceType('t1.micro')
    .withMinCount(1)
    .withMonitoring(true);
```